# SSIS Bulk Insert Task optimization options

Tags: ssis

I am running a foreach loop on some rather big tsv (tab delimited files) which i first convert from utf8 -> unicode and then load them from the text files using a bulk insert task.

I am looking in a way to improve the loading times of the bulk insert task.

what i have done so far.

-All indexes in the db are DISABLED.

-All `TransactionOption` options are set to **NotSupported**.

-Set properties of the bulk task as i think are best. This is where i need advice:

[image]

Comment: What is the definition of the table that you are inserting into, including indexes and constraints?

Comment: It's not one table , they are hundrends...You see it is in a foreach loop. Every table is different

Comment: Is there any consistency between them?  Are they all heaps, all clustered indexes.  Are FKs used as a convention?  Is your database in simple recovery model or something else?